# Closing a windows application after bat file runs

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In my batch file I opened a file and printed its contents.  Now I am trying to close the application.  I used taskkill /f /im Ptedit50.exe from the cmd line and the program closes.  I am having trouble getting it to work in the batch file.  When I add that line after the print command they program exits and the print command never executes.  If I insert the line at the end of the batch file the program does not exit.  Where should I place the taskkill /f /im Ptedit50.exe line?

```
@echo off
setlocal

title My First batch file
echo Hello!
start Ptedit50.exe "c:\My Labels\PraxisBadge.lbx"  

call :SendCtrlP "Name in Windowtitle"

exit /b

:SendCtrlP <app>
setlocal
set vbs=%Temp%\_.vbs
>%vbs% echo set s = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
>>%vbs% echo s.appactivate "%~1"
>>%vbs% echo s.sendkeys "^p"
>>%vbs% echo s.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
exit /b

taskkill /f /im Ptedit50.exe
exit /b
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Batch + JScript Hybrid example.  I added a couple 2 second sleeps to allow the target program time to process the requests.  Usually, applications launch a separate Print dialog, so I changed it to send the enter keypress to the Print dialog.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: The first line in the script is...
:: in Batch, a valid IF command that does nothing.
:: in JScript, a conditional compilation IF statement that is false.
::             So the following section is omitted until the next "[at]end".
:: Note: the "[at]then" is required for Batch to prevent a syntax error.
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Batch Section

@echo off
:: Open Labels
start Ptedit50.exe "c:\My Labels\PraxisBadge.lbx"
:: Wait 2 Seconds
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 2000 >nul
:: Send Ctrl+P and Enter
CScript //E:JScript //Nologo "%~f0" "Name in Windowtitle" "^p"
CScript //E:JScript //Nologo "%~f0" "Print" "~"
:: Wait 2 Seconds
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 2000 >nul
:: Kill Program
taskkill /f /im Ptedit50.exe
exit /b 0

:: End of Batch
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@end
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// JScript Section

try
{
    var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');
    var Title = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
    var Message = WScript.Arguments.Item(1);
    WshShell.AppActivate(Title);
    WshShell.SendKeys(Message);
    WScript.Quit(0);
}
catch(e)
{
    WScript.Echo(e);
    WScript.Quit(1);
}
WScript.Quit(2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  If you are ever in Phoenix I'll buy you a beer

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is from my perspective straight forward, so I would avoid usage of those `setlocal`, `call` and `exit /b` parts of your code as there is no real need in this code to jump there and back again rather than executing codes line by line.

I don't have your application to fully test it, but if I try it with notepad and text file following code is working for me:

```
    @echo off
    title My First batch file
    echo Hello!

    start notepad.exe test.txt

    REM call :SendCtrlP "Name in Windowtitle"

    :SendCtrlP <app>
    REM setlocal
    set vbs=%Temp%\my.vbs
    >%vbs% echo set s = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    >>%vbs% echo s.appactivate "Name in Windowtitle"
    >>%vbs% echo s.sendkeys "^p"
    >>%vbs% echo s.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
    cscript //nologo %vbs%
    ping -n 5 localhost > NUL
    if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%

    REM exit /b
    taskkill /f /im notepad.exe

    REM exit /b
    echo enter code here
    pause
```

I have REM'd your code intentionally for easier view what was removed.

This part is there in order to simulate wait/sleep on older or desktop OS systems.

```
    ping -n 5 localhost > NUL
```

On server system this can be replaced by command `sleep`.

Seems that reason why it was not working for you is that you have actually killed your program before .vbs was able to print it out, therefore the `sleep` put in place and additionally as stated in the beginning usage of `setlocal` is not really necessary in such straight forward and simple batch files.

Hope this helps